# Live Mesh has screwed up my file permissions

Tags: file, permissions, live, mesh

I got the bright idea of using Live Mesh to sync up my development directories between my laptop and desktop machines.  It appears that the permission on any new files that are added through Live Mesh do not inherit permissions from the parent directory.  Now I cannot overwrite the permissions on those files.  I keep getting an "Access is Denied" error when attempting to do so, even if I am running Windows Explorer as administrator.  I have two questions:

1. How can I modify the file permissions to allow them to inherit again?
2. Has anyone used Live Mesh to do this sort of thing?  Or should I be using FolderShare instead?

Comment: Really, you ought to use a proper version control system and not toys like Live Mesh or Dropbox.

Comment: I use version control as well.  The synchronization of files works well when I have to leave the office and I'm not ready to commit my changes (maybe I am in the middle of a build-breaking change).  I'd like to get started at home where I left off in the office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [TakeOwn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024(WS.10).aspx) command to regain access to your files. You may also need to use the [cacls](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872.aspx) command depending on the state of your files.

In my experience, Windows Live Mesh does not handle syncing files between multiple user accounts. Windows Live Folder Sync seems to handle this better.

Comment: Thanks, TakeOwn has saved the day :)  I'll give Folder Sync a try.